# Image is not in the right position

Tags: graphics, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Why does the image is not at the point where I included it in the code, but at the end of the part?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{"Morel Upsim"}
\author{"Vorname Nachname"}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gradient.jpg} %I also tried [h] and [!ht]
\end{figure}

\part{"Generated text"}

From a bird flew open space\ldots you what with a muffled drone. - Look, - Missiles? Don't Panic inscribed in a page for good place then? Ford was because it was all the greatest computer that they said. - said Trillian from the inside of supplies slight cough, - said Arthur, rather involved being a which Ford carried round a house. Chapter 14 The aircar trip brought other mouse said, and the Vl'hurgs, resplendent in considerable stress, ulcers and Damogran Arthur found himself out of its

olive. Drink\ldots but\ldots very much. As a thoroughly squalid. At kids at Arthur. - Well, you the bar, - the wide and it were coordinates gabbleblotchits the Galaxy isn't it? - it from Ford. - It's gold, - As the screens again muttering incoherently. - a moment, - said Trillian. - That's it! The almost the water spout. Up, up nothing. So if making fun of but he to reassure. - said Deep Thought. - asked plaintively. Ford Prefect, - Shhh, - Appropriate time? - he yelped. -

traditional due Slartibartfast turned speech and it seemed to ethics who now it had settled now that Zaphod and it had been there. It's more seconds. - there wouldn't be the local Bugblatter down it occurs to program in chorus. Deep Thought. - he's\ldots - as the Great And to the eye Phouchg flinging will finally stopped talking about the and the other what to the rubble that won't enjoy doing it? - Dunno, - What's my home of flying saucer at the computer.

whom the trading scouts. Ford Prefect life far the into hyperspace for him, - said forget up, wrote it new I speak Vogon! - Yes. - Though I doing now, and dried before contact yet I beg your planet you see. Ford and disappeared and a have to be telling people out because Reason was out it was almost, but it was the square of her with you? - urged Loonquawl. - Telephone number? - The Hitch Hiker's Guide to trim it tends turning

swift burst out of it stared into one ever since be aware, the captain didn't matter that anyway, you really was just very moment and woken him to the light around in its through the biros brave man big and took him blankly in marble-topped tables and Marvin and know little piggy forehead. decides electric death at the salient points of thing they still engrossed in your white and started winking in Improbability of all with of a figurehead - Oh, just gaped.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Because you're inserting the graphics inside a floating environment called `figure`. This is not a prerequisite in order to add pictures to your document. If you want to avoid the floating (or moving around of things), simply use something like `\begin{center}\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gradient.jpg}\end{center}`.

Comment: See (possible duplicates) [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and/or [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).